# Get colorpicker values in html?

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

Here is the code of my color picker.
http://jsfiddle.net/7jg4e/728/

```
<img id="1" alt="test"  src="https:/test.com/IMGService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&amp;postid=7406&amp;width=100%&amp;height=142&amp;RenderText=[field title]&amp;TextSize=96&amp;TextColor=%23ff0000&amp;BgColor=%23ffffff">
```

Here is my img tag which is api convert text into image. i want to add colopicker to this image tag so user can change the color of image so i have colorpicker and every colorpick's out put with javascript or with Jquarry we need to use id tag but how i can get color name value in my BgColor=
I hope you understand my point. 
i mean i want if user use color picker and pick one color its automatic update in BgColor in img filed  like bellow

```
<img id="1" alt="test"  src="https:/test.com/IMGService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&amp;postid=7406&amp;width=100%&amp;height=142&amp;RenderText=[field title]&amp;TextSize=96&amp;TextColor=%23ff0000&amp;BgColor=%23**Color Picker color value Here**">
```

I want print colorpicker value here. is it possible

```
;BgColor=%23**Color Picker color value Here**">
```

Sorry For Poor English.

Comment: Why do you need an API for this?

Comment: @aloisdg Hi, thanks for reply, no i mean this is api service i used here , it have value which provide background color so i want to print color value here when user pick color from colorpicker. hope you got my point

Comment: @aloisdg You can ignore the api line from my question. i just want to know is it possible to print colorpicker value in bgcolor= "Here "  with javascript or not if yes then how if not the can php do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let src = 'URL' + $('#color').val().replace('#','');
$('#1').attr('src', src);
```

Id 1 should not be valid within js/jquery.

Comment: Thanks For your time and reply, can you please make a live example at  http://jsfiddle.net so i can understand it batter, im new to this hope you dont mind it. Thanks again

Comment: i got this output with above code <img id="1" alt="test" src="URL123456">

Comment: thanks its work , you make my day , thanks alot , i had spend 3 days to this issue .. anyways thanks again ... have a nice day.