# How to change values in realtime with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tqjuco4x/1/

Here is my last question : [Get colorpicker values in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036586/get-colorpicker-values-in-html)

I dont want to update it in my last question as its new problem and new thing I want to add in my code so that's why I ask in new question, hope editors not mind it.

How I can get live value without click on Change Color button. I mean in my code I have to pick color and then click on Change Color button so  is their any way to do it live, I mean I want to remove that button and when user pick color its update live ?

```
<button id="triggerImg">Change Color</button>
```

Is that possible in my code. hope you got my point.
Sorry for poor English.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: you can use onkeyup event on textbox using javascript

Comment: @AndrewL sure , i will do this

Comment: @MandarDhadve can you explain im new to these things , anyways thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. Use the `.change` event.

```
$("#clr1").on("change", function(){
    console.log("Change color to: " + this.val());
});
```

---

Edit: You're actually using JSColor library for your colour picker. I recommend you clean it up a bit if you're not using the other one.

What you should do is the following:

Create a function to listen to font edit:

```
function updateFont(color, jso){
    var hexStr = jso.toHEXString();
    console.log(hexStr);
}
```

And Create a function for your background change if needed.

Then change the input elements from:

`<input class="jscolor" name="color" id="clr1" value="ab2567">`

To:

`<input class="jscolor" id="clr1" onchange="updateFont(this.jscolor)" name="color" value="ab2567">`

Here's a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqjuco4x/7/) for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help please if you dont mind can you explain i mean make a live example on jsfiddle, im new thats why i need some help to understand the working of codes

Comment: Hi , i dont know what happen but  code is not working .. look here http://jsfiddle.net/egq3udsb/ please see whats going wrong ..

Comment: @deccc Put the scripts at the top of the `head` tag and make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Yes i do all things but i dont know why java code not replace new image when color pick ?

Comment: You're not. I just modified your code to do those things and it worked. If you're having further issues I recommend asking another question as comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: sorry for that, i tried fresh code on my site and on jsbin , https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp, even again on jsfiddle , if i ask new question editors ask me to update my previous question and vote negative. sorry again , thanks a lot for your time .im unable to figure it out thats why i ask , anyways thanks again .. it matter for me your provide your knowledge to newbie .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `change` on the text field. You can find the Docs [jQuery docs here](https://api.jquery.com/change/). And then change the CSS inside the callback function of `change` using jQuery css [Read the docs for css here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
$( ".your-input-text" ).change(function() {
     //Change the CSS here.
     $( this ).css([
           color: $(this).val(), "background": "#fff"
     ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So i edited your jsfiddle

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0b1o8uz/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');

$('#clr1').change(function(){
let src = 'https:/test.com/IMGService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&amp;postid=7406&amp;width=100%&amp;height=142&amp;RenderText=[field title]&amp;TextSize=96&amp;TextColor=%23ff0000&amp;BgColor=%23' + $('#clr1').val().replace('#','');
$('#testImg').attr('src', src);
});

$('#clr2').change(function(){
let src = 'https:/test.com/IMGService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&amp;postid=7406&amp;width=100%&amp;height=142&amp;RenderText=[field title]&amp;TextSize=96&amp;TextColor=%23ff0000&amp;BgColor=%23' + $('#clr2').val().replace('#','');
$('#testImg').attr('src', src);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not update the values , please look again , thanks for time and help

Comment: Hi, @jaapaap can you look it , as its not update values from javascript into html .. please look again in your code .. thanks again for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want to do is -

```
<input id="txt_Search" type="text" onchange="Call()" />
<script>
function Call()
{
   //your code
}

</script>
```

Or, using simple jQuery

```
$("#txt_Search").keyup( function() {
    var searchQuery = $("#txt_Search").val();
    //your code
});
```

Comment: can you please explain it , i mean live example  on jsfiddle , thanks for help and time.